# Angular ng-repeat, reordering animation slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a carousel slider in angular, I have ng-repeat with `orderBy:'id'` and when i click next slide button, id change it.

Look at my JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/owen10/hnqmfg9j/)

I have div with ng-repeat:

```
<div class="slide" ng-repeat="slide in slides | orderBy:'id*1'">
    <p>
      {{ slide.value.name }}
    </p>
</div>
```

And I have function to sort new item list:

```
$scope.nextSlide = () => {
  let items = $scope.slides
  let countItems = items.length

  for (let i = 0; i < countItems; i++) {
    let z = items[i].id % countItems;
    items[i].id = z + (countItems - 1);
  }
}
```

And my problem:

[image: Look at this gif:]

First occurs animate, then scope new ordering item and blink to new slide. Any ideas? How can I animated reordering in `ng-repeat`?

Comment: your jsfiddle doesn't seem to reproduce that bad behaviour. If you try and get it there it will be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you reorder first, so that the first slides are in the 'normal' order and when you click next, the 'reordered' slides show up...

I just don\t understand why you would reorder on "next()"

Comment: I reorder my list, because first slides must go to last item, this slider must be carousel :(

Comment: Ok, I now get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are tackling the problem the wrong way, about your animation.
Let's say you have 2 items always visible.
1 | 2 | 3 | 4

When you click next, it should:
 - slide on the left (animation)
 - THEN, once animation is done, you do:
 - reorder items (2 first at the back) AND - at the same time - recenter the list.

I think in your small demo, you just forget to recenter the list. 
I guess it all depends on the way you are doing your animation as well.